# Disable backlight and permanently show ambient display using root?

Tags: root-access, 8.0-oreo, backlight

I own a Rooted Nexus 5x on the Pixel^2 8.0.0 ROM, and when I saw a real Pixel 2 on its charger at night I noticed that it didn't have "backlight" on (black was actually black) and it permanently showed the ambient display.

I don't see a settings option for this, can I turn it on using root?

Answer (score 1):

It's called Always On display and you ideally shouldn't be using it on your Nexus 5X because its an LCD screen, not AMOLED like Pixel. You can flash a different ROM which has this feature or if you have Android 8.1, it's already baked in all devices just needs to be manually activated. Follow [this XDA article](https://www.xda-developers.com/enable-google-pixel-2-always-on-display-on-nexus-6p-pixel-xl/)

You need to install Andromeda Substrantum on your phone. Download Pixel Enabler or Always-on-enabler subtrantum theme and install it.

Comment: Alright, so I don't want to burn my screen (I didn't realize that until now) but can I still turn off the backlight so the Adaptive Display doesn't light up at night?